# I can't display icons in the menu/actionBar (minSDK 17 and targetSDK 25), what's wrong?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

- compileSdkVersion 25
- minSdkVersion 17
- dependencies compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'

This is my menu in /res/menu/main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/create_order"
            android:title="Create Order"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_playlist_add_black_24dp"
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_setting"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="Settings"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>

    </menu>
```

And this is the MainActivity:

```
package com.example.fulvio.bitsandpizzas;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

I'm not getting where my code is wrong, neither I can see the icon directly in the ActionBar and in the overflow menu, but only text.

[image]

I've already read the other similar questions (and answers), but none helped me

Answer (score 0):

Android does not show icon anymore by default in menu. You have to use retrospection to achieve this (in your activity):

```
@Override
      protected boolean onPrepareOptionsPanel(View view, Menu menu) {
        if(menu != null){
          if("MenuBuilder".equals(menu.getClass().getSimpleName())){
            try{
              Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                  "setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
              m.setAccessible(true);
              m.invoke(menu, true);
            }
            catch(NoSuchMethodException e){
              //
            }
          }
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsPanel(view, menu);
      }
```

I'm not fond of this method, but I did not find any other solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
app:showAsAction = "always"
```

to

```
android:showAsAction = "always"
```

**Or**

You can use `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity` :

```
package com.example.fulvio.bitsandpizzas;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't use android:showAsAction` because "Should use `app:showAsAction` with the appcompat library"

I can't use `AppCompatActivity` because the app stop working because 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity`